# Circuitikz: using sans-serif fonts for text

Tags: circuitikz, sans-serif

I want to make all the text on my circuit diagram to be in a sans-serif font. Does anyone know how I would do this? THanks

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=0.5in]{geometry} % Defines margins

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
    resistors/scale=0.8, % smaller R
    capacitors/scale=0.7, % even smaller C
    diodes/scale=0.6, % small diodes
    transistors/scale=1.2, % bigger BJTs
    transistors/thickness=4, 
    transistor circle/relative thickness=0.5,   
    bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.25
} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw 
            (0,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){BC548}
            (-2,0) to [eC, *-o, l=10<\micro\farad>] (-4,0) node[left]{IN}
            (-2,3) to [R, l=100K] (-2,0) -- (Q1.B)
            (-2,0) to [R, l=20K] (-2,-3)
            (-2,3) -- (0,3)
            to [R, l=1K] (0,1) -- (Q1.C)
            (0,1) to [eC, -o, l=10<\micro\farad>] (4,1) node[right]{OUT}
            (Q1.E) -- (0,-1) 
            to [R, -*, l=47<\ohm>] (0,-3) -- (-2,-3)
            (0,-1) -- (2,-1) 
            to [eC, l=100<\micro\farad>] (2,-3) -- (0,-3)
            (0,3.3) node[vcc]{\qty{6}{\volt}} -- (0,3)
            (0,-3) -- (0,-3.1) node[ground]{}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=0.5in]{geometry} % Defines margins

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
    resistors/scale=0.8, % smaller R
    capacitors/scale=0.7, % even smaller C
    diodes/scale=0.6, % small diodes
    transistors/scale=1.2, % bigger BJTs
    transistors/thickness=4,
    transistor circle/relative thickness=0.5,
    bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.25
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[font=\sffamily]
\sisetup{mode = text,
reset-text-family = false ,
reset-text-series = false ,
reset-text-shape = false
}
        \draw
            (0,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){BC548}
            (-2,0) to [eC, *-o, l=10<\micro\farad>] (-4,0) node[left]{IN}
            (-2,3) to [R, l=100K] (-2,0) -- (Q1.B)
            (-2,0) to [R, l=20K] (-2,-3)
            (-2,3) -- (0,3)
            to [R, l=1K] (0,1) -- (Q1.C)
            (0,1) to [eC, -o, l=10<\micro\farad>] (4,1) node[right]{OUT}
            (Q1.E) -- (0,-1)
            to [R, -*, l=47<\ohm>] (0,-3) -- (-2,-3)
            (0,-1) -- (2,-1)
            to [eC, l=100<\micro\farad>] (2,-3) -- (0,-3)
            (0,3.3) node[vcc]{\qty{6}{\volt}} -- (0,3)
            (0,-3) -- (0,-3.1) node[ground]{}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum:**
In the case that in your document are many circuit schemes and like to have `\sffamily` fonts only in `circuitikz` images, than is sensible to move `siunitx` and font settings to document preamble and use macro `\AtBeginEnvironment` defined in the `etoolbox` as is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=1in, right=0.5in]{geometry} % Defines margins
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{
    resistors/scale=0.8, % smaller R
    capacitors/scale=0.7, % even smaller C
    diodes/scale=0.6, % small diodes
    transistors/scale=1.2, % bigger BJTs
    transistors/thickness=4,
    transistor circle/relative thickness=0.5,
    bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.25
        }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{circuitikz}{%
    \sisetup{mode = text,
reset-text-family = false,
reset-text-series = false,
 reset-text-shape = false
            },
font=\sffamily}


\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){BC548}
    (-2,0) to [eC, *-o, l=10<\micro\farad>] (-4,0) node[left]{IN}
    (-2,3) to [R, l=100K] (-2,0) -- (Q1.B)
    (-2,0) to [R, l=20K] (-2,-3)
    (-2,3) -- (0,3)
    to [R, l=1K] (0,1) -- (Q1.C)
    (0,1) to [eC, -o, l=10<\micro\farad>] (4,1) node[right]{OUT}
    (Q1.E) -- (0,-1)
    to [R, -*, l=47<\ohm>] (0,-3) -- (-2,-3)
    (0,-1) -- (2,-1)
    to [eC, l=100<\micro\farad>] (2,-3) -- (0,-3)
    (0,3.3) node[vcc]{\qty{6}{\volt}} -- (0,3)
    (0,-3) -- (0,-3.1) node[ground]{}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Produced image is the same as before.

Comment: @KenEly, see addendum to answer.